# Enabling opening and closing tag guidelines in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2013, notepad++

I've recently started using Visual Studio quite heavily since starting to develop in .Net
I really like the intellisense as it increases my productivity by allowing me to code faster. Previously when authoring CSS I would just use Notepad ++ and I got very used to some of the little features that this awesome text editor possessed however, now that I am doing the bulk of my work in Visual Studio 2013 I want to try and avoid having too many environments open at once. With this in mind, there is one feature inparticular that I would like to try and replicate in Visual Studio when editing CSS or indeed any other type of code.

In Notepad ++ it automatically includes a sort of guideline which runs down the page between the opening and closing tags of elements as shown below:

[image: Notepad ++]

My question is, how do I replicate this behaviour in Visual Studio 2013 as the currently setup I have at the moment isn't as clear/productive as you can see below:

[image: Visual Studio 2013]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Definitely install the [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of free extensions you can use to do this. These will run on any of the Visual Studio versions except Express, which does not support extensions.

You can duplicate this with the [Indent Guides](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30) extension.

[image: Indent Guides on white background]

You can also use the Structure Visualizer Feature of the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/).

[image: Structure Visualizer on black background]

Note: The backgrounds in the example are different because they are taken on different machines with different themes.

Comment: This is perfect. Thankyou very much. I knew there would be an extension it's just knowing what it's called that's the issue :-)